# Sending large files across TCP in .Net

Tags: .net, sockets

I need to send large files (> 50 meg) over TCP. I have searched all the posted questions and answers, but haven't found viable solution. When I try to send, my sending program sends a few packets and then aborts with this error: System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

As for my receiving client, the Listener.Pending() state is always false, so it never reads any packets. My code is very close to working, but I need some eagle eyes to look at it and help, please.

```
Public Sub SendTCPFile(Address As String, ModelName As String, FileName As String)
    Dim SendingBuffer As Byte() = Nothing
    Dim Client As TcpClient = Nothing
    Dim NetStream As NetworkStream = Nothing
    Dim BufferSize As Integer = 1024
    Try
        Client = New TcpClient(Address, PortNumber)
        NetStream = Client.GetStream()
        Dim FS As FileStream = New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim NumberOfPackets As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(FS.Length) / Convert.ToDouble(BufferSize)))
        Dim CurrentPacketLength As Integer, TotalLength As Integer = CInt(FS.Length), counter As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To NumberOfPackets - 1
            If TotalLength > BufferSize Then
                CurrentPacketLength = BufferSize
                TotalLength = TotalLength - CurrentPacketLength
            Else
                CurrentPacketLength = TotalLength
            End If
            SendingBuffer = New Byte(CurrentPacketLength) {}
           FS.Read(SendingBuffer, 0, CurrentPacketLength)
            NetStream.Write(SendingBuffer, 0, CInt(SendingBuffer.Length))
        Next
        FS.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteLog("EXCEPTION in SendTCPFile")
    Finally
        NetStream.Close()
        Client.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub ReceiveTCPFile(Address As String, ModelName As String)
    Dim Listener As TCPListener = Nothing
    Try
        Listener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, PortNumber)
        Listener.Start()
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteLog("EXCEPTION in SendTCPFile")
    EndTry
    Dim BufferSize As Integer = 1024
    ReceivingBuffer = New Byte(BufferSize) {}
    Dim BytesReceived As Integer
    While True
        Dim Client As TcpClient = Nothing
        Dim NetStream As NetworkStream = Nothing
        Try
             If Listener.Pending() Then
                  Client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient()
                  NetStream = Client.GetStream()
                  Dim FS As FileStream = New FileStream(SaveFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
                  While (BytesReceived = NetStream.Read(ReceivingBuffer, 0, ReceivingBuffer.Length)) > 0
                       FS.Write(ReceivingBuffer, 0, BytesReceived)
                  End While
                  FS.Close()
                  NetStream.Close()
                  Client.Close()
            End If 'Listener.Pending
        Catch ex As Exception
            WriteLog("EXCEPTION in SendTCPFile")
            NetStream.Close()
        End Try
    End While
End Sub 'ReceiveTCPFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to calculate `NumberOfPackets` on the sender side.  Just keep reading from the `FileStream` until you reach EOF, sending whatever you read.  Just like you do on the receiving side when you keep reading until disconnected, writing to file whatever you receive.

```vb
Public Sub SendTCPFile(Address As String, ModelName As String, FileName As String)
    Dim Client As TcpClient = Nothing
    Dim NetStream As NetworkStream = Nothing
    Try
        Client = New TcpClient(Address, PortNumber)
        NetStream = Client.GetStream()
        Dim FS As FileStream = New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim BufferSize As Integer = 1024
        Dim SendingBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(BufferSize) {}
        Dim PacketLength As Integer = 0
        While (PacketLength = FS.Read(SendingBuffer, 0, SendingBuffer.Length)) > 0
          NetStream.Write(SendingBuffer, 0, PacketLength)
        End While
        FS.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteLog("EXCEPTION in SendTCPFile")
    Finally
        NetStream.Close()
        Client.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

As for your `Listener.Pending` issue, that can only mean that your client never attempts to connect to the server, so there is no connection for the server to accept.  You can't send data to the server before the server has accepted the connection.  The `TcpClient` constructor raises an exception if it can't establish a connection.  So, if the constructor is not failing, but `Pending` is always false, then the client must be connecting to some other server than your own.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding to my query.